# Mysql помощь при удалении запеси

Tags: mysql, lazarus

Как исправить ошибку, чтобы удаление проходило?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

SQL запросы пишутся в верхнем регистре. Попробуйте.

Comment: Неверно, SQL не зависит от регистра.  Пожалуйста, подкрепите ваш ответ ссылкой на документацию.